# git clone : HTTP request fatal

Tags: git, github, debian, openstreetmap

I want to install osm2pgsql on my debian system but here is the error I get :

> git clone https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql.git 
>   Cloning into osm2pgsql... 
>   error: Failed connect to github.com:443; 
>   Operation now inprogress while accessing https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql.git/info/refs
>
> fatal: HTTP request failed

I can see no other way to install osm2pgsql, so what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this happen to me, and I was able to clone using http:// instead of https:// like this:

```
git clone http://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql.git
```

Comment: I guess you meant "git clone http"://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql.git". But I still have the same error, except the port which changes. Could it be a proxy issue?

Comment: Thanks. Glad you were able to do it.